# Math.Random Function in Java

Tags: java

I have used the below Java code to generate random numbers using math.random function

```
public class randomnumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int num = generatenumber(35);
        while(num>0 & num < 35) {
            System.out.println(num);
            break;
        }
        //System.out.println("greater");
    }

    public static int generatenumber(int n) {
        double d= Math.random() * 100;

        int x = (int)d;
        //System.out.println(x);
        return x;
    }
}
```

However, the output is not being displayed when the number is greater than 35.  I want the program to print until `num` is less than 35.  What should I change so that it will do that?

Clarification:

Each time this Math.random() generates a random number. On the the first call, if the number generated is greater than 35 ,then I want this function "generate number " to be called again so that next time if the number is less than 35, that number is printed.

Comment: your while loop is telling it not to print if it is greater than 35 or less than 0. Also, what's the point the `n` variable? It's not used.

Comment: You want it to print if it's greater than 35? If so, your condition is backwards. You are saying "*if num is less than 35: print num*".

Comment: You can use the `Random` class too, it's slightly easier to use than `Math.random()` (you don't need to multiply).

Comment: Each time this math.random() generates a random number. On the the first call,if the number generated is greater than 35 ,then I want this function "generate number " to be called again so that next time if the number is less than 35 ,that number is printed. Current Behaviour is,output is displayed only if number is less than 35.When the generated number is greated than 35 output is displayed as blank. But I want this generatenumber() to be called again and again till the number is less than 35 and gets printed.Hope I am not confusing.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

```
int num=generatenumber(35);
while(num>0 & num < 35)
{
    System.out.println(num);
    break;
}
```

You mean to generate and test many times but in fact you're passing zero or one time in your loop depending on the value of `num`.

The correct code according to your "specs" is

```
int num;
while(true)
{
    num = generatenumber(35);
    System.out.println(num);

    if (num>0 && num < 35)  // note the double &&: logic and not arithmetic
    {

    break;
    }
}
```

General note: while loops with conditions are most of the time more complicated than with a `true`. You have to think of an initialization AND a termination condition, which is sometimes the same. Too much copy/paste and errors...

shmosel suggestion is even better using `do/while`:

```
int num;
do
{
    num = generatenumber(35);
    System.out.println(num);        
}
while (num>0 && num < 35);  // note the double &&: logic and not arithmetic
```

Comment: I think this is a good case for a do-while, especially once you're declaring `num` outside the loop. But I agree with your observation about loops in general. I'll often start with a `while(true)` and then refactor if I see it can be standardized.

Comment: Each time this math.random() generates a random number. On the the first call,if the number generated is greater than 35 ,then I want this function "generate number " to be called again so that next time if the number is less than 35 ,that number is printed. Current Behaviour is,output is displayed only if number is less than 35.When the generated number is greated than 35 output is displayed as blank. But I want this generatenumber() to be called again and again till the number is less than 35 and gets printed.Hope I am not confusing.Thanks in advance

Comment: " test many times the same value if num > 35" is not true. Nothing here is done many times.

Answer (score 1):

There are three mistakes:

1. You should use && instead of &. This two operators are quite different.
2. The line "int num=generatenumber(35);" should be inside the while too.
3. You need to remove the break statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100);
    for (; num > 35; num = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100)) {
        System.out.println(num + " is ignored");
    }
    System.out.println(num + " is ok");
}
```

Comment: Each time this math.random() generates a random number. On the the first call,if the number generated is greater than 35 ,then I want this function "generate number " to be called again so that next time if the number is less than 35 ,that number is printed. Current Behaviour is,output is displayed only if number is less than 35.When the generated number is greated than 35 output is displayed as blank. But I want this generatenumber() to be called again and again till the number is less than 35 and gets printed.Hope I am not confusing.Thanks in advance